# Why can you assume the current remains the same after changing resistance?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

In my physics textbook there is a question about a circuit:

[image]

In question b) We find out the current in the circuit is 0.003A. This is before the voltmeter is added.

In question c) a voltmeter is added that affects the p.d across the first 1k resistor which causes its voltage to drop from 3.0V to 2.0V. In the mark scheme they say R(from B to A) = 666.7 ohms which is means they did 2/0.003. How is it known the current doesn't change at all, or am I missing something?

Comment: Cant really get what you want an answer for. I would rather recommend that you first read about an ideal voltmeter. That should ideally solve your issue.

Comment: @sbp I am wondering how it is known the current across the resistor remains the same, even though the effective resistance of the circuit changed due to them adding the voltmeter

Comment: Shouldnt that ideally happen when you measure something? The measurement shouldnt ideally alter any observable. Now the question is how can a voltmeter really do this - should have a very high resistance!

Comment: @sbp Yes I understand that but the voltmeter in the question has a resistance of 2000Ohms (in the mark scheme) so why did the current in the resistor at BA not change

Comment: Could you just post the complete question? I mean the full text before the subpart begins.

Comment: @sbp I added it

Comment: Say you want to measure the PD across the BA resistor - you would place it in a parallel config. So the current does change if it isnt an ideal voltmeter - as stated in the question.

Comment: @sbp But the current across the BA resistor remains the same at 0.003A, thats why I'm confused!

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion? Please post your working.

Comment: @sbp I didn't. My working shows the current before the voltmeter is added is 0.003 given by 6/(1000+1000).  And the mark scheme says once the resistor is added and the p.d across BA is 2.0V  the resistance is 666.7 ohms, meaning they did 2/0.003 (using the current before it was added).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the mark scheme they say R(from B to A) = 666.7 ohms which is means they did 2/0.003. How is it known the current doesn't change at all, or am I missing something?

The given solution is incorrect.

If we connect the voltmeter as shown and measure 2 V, then we know that 
$$ 6 \frac{R'}{R'+1000} = 2$$
where $R'$ is the parallel combination of the voltmeter and the 1 kohm resistor, from the voltage divider rule. This means $R'$ must be 500 ohms.

Therefore 
$$\frac{1000 R}{1000+R} = 500,$$
from which we can find
$$R = 1000.$$

Sometimes the problem is just that the guy who wrote the textbook didn't pay much attention when writing the solutions.

> How is it known the current doesn't change at all, or am I missing something?

A well-designed voltmeter should have a burden resistance of $10^6\ {\rm \Omega}$ or higher, so often it is reasonable to make this assumption. However, it should not have been made in this particular problem.

Comment: My working did keep pointing towards 1000 but I assumed I was wrong lol. Thanks for the clarification :)